# TS2322: Type '{ ready: false; session: null; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<S & withAuthState>'

Tags: javascript, typescript, reactxp

I have the following interface:

```
export interface withAuthState {
  ready: boolean,
  session: any
}
```

And the following HOC:

```
const withAuth = <P extends withAuthProps, S extends withAuthState>(
  WrappedComponent: new (props: P) => RX.Component<P, S>
) =>    class WithAuth extends RX.Component<P & withAuthProps, S & withAuthState> {
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);

          this.state = {
            ready: false,
            session: null
          };
        }
    }
```

I'm unable to set the state in the constructor. The error is:

```
TS2322: Type '{ ready: false; session: null; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<S & withAuthState>'.
```

I'm clearly missing something here, but I do not know what.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `class WithAuth extends RX.Component<P & withAuthProps, S & withAuthState> ` This will not compile without `P` and `S`. Where are these defined ? could you post your full code ?

Comment: oups sorry, this is a High Order Component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the state may have other properties, which you can't initialize because you don't know about them in your HOC. Consider the following:

```
class MyComponent extends RX.Component<withAuthProps, withAuthState & { myStateProp: number }>{}    
const MyComponentWithAuth = withAuth(MyComponent);
let comp = new MyComponentWithAuth({});
// myStateProp does not exist on state because you did not initialize it in your HOC even though the property is required
comp.state.myStateProp
```

If you are ok with this behavior, you can just use a type assertion when you initialize the state:

```
this.state = {
    ready: false,
    session: null
} as S & withAuthState;
```

Comment: The type assertion does not compile. I have 3 errors. Identifier expected. The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type. 'S' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

Comment: @OlivierMATROT wops, you are in a tsx, `<>` does not work for assertions, you must use `as`, will update in a second